# Import bsh interpreter statement cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I copied the bean shell files into LIBS directory and I get this error in Eclipse: "import bsh cannot be resolved"
on these statements 
import bsh.EvalError;
import bsh.Interpreter;

I read that I should copied the bsh files into LIBS and couldnt find anything else that I need to do. Thanks.